# Add color to JQuery Terminal

Tags: jquery-terminal

I am trying to add color the the jquery terminal like a bash terminal in linux.

I have tried the same arrangement of color codes

```
\033]01;31\] # pink
\033]00m\]   # white
\033]01;36\] # bold green
\033]02;36\] # green
\033]01;34\] # blue
\033]01;33\] # bold yellow
```

and there is no color options.

Comment: The escape code should be `\033[01;31m` open bracket instead of closing and in new version of jQuery Terminal you also need unix_formatting.js file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function I use is like so for javascript

```
function teal(message) {
    return "[[gb;teal;black]" + message + "]";
}
```

Just wrap the string like the above.

The first colour is the text color and the second color is the background.

The gb at the start are for string formatting;

> **g** = glow  & **b** = bold

You can also under line and make them italic aswell

> **i** = italic & **u** = underline

In the string, **make sure not** to have any `[` or `]` as this will affect the formatting. Use the escape character `\[` or `\]` and it should work.

It will also work in C# as I have done this myself and should see no reason it wouldn't work with the likes of Java strings either.

Comment: The colors, will it work with hex code as well? like #FF0123

Comment: Yes, you can also use hex colors, they were supported long before names were added.